# Java if statement not working as expected

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm studying for a java programming exam, and I'm still a beginner. My problem in the if statement is:

```
int z;

if (z==1);
{//calculates area}

if (z==2)
{//calculates volume}
```

The goal is that if the user chooses 1 he'll find the area calculated and if he the user chooses 2 the volume will be calculated. However, in the output the area and volume are being calculated whatever the user chooses. Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove the `;` after the condition. Otherwise, the if statement is empty, and the code block following it is always executed.

```
if (z==1)
{//calculates area}

if (z==2)
{//calculates volume}
```

Or even better:

```
if (z==1) {
    //calculates area
} else if (z==2) {
    //calculates volume
}
```

since both conditions can't be true.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to remove **semicolon (;)** after the ***if (condition)***.
   ***If(condition)*** is not a statement and so semicolon should not be inserted.
2. Double slash (//) has been used to comment out a line. That's why one of the brackets of if clause gets out of use.

The code should be looked like following:

```
int z;

if (z==1)
{
    //calculates area
}

if (z==2)
{
    //calculates volume
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon (;) from the end of first line.

Learn to format your code according specification

```
int z;
if (z==1) {
    //calculates area
}

if (z==2) {
   //calculates volume
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking when talking about code conventions: There _should_ be a `blank line` between local var declaration and first statement. And there _should_ be spaces around the `==`. [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html#487)